# linux kernel linked list - list_for_each_entry

Tags: linux, linked-list, kernel

I want to see what I have in list using list_for_each_entry, but I couldn't.

I defined message_list and channel just like this way.

```
typedef struct message_list{
    struct list_head msg_list;
    char* msg;
    int len;
}message_list;

typedef struct channel{
    int p_cnt;      // need to be initialized
    pid_t pid[2];       // need to be initialized

    message_list path0; //pid[0] use this path when he sends messages
    message_list path1; //pid[1] use this path when he sends messages
}channel;
```

and I write this code for testing.

```
list_for_each_entry(tmp, &chs[ch].path1.msg_list, msg_list){
    printk("msg[%s]\n", tmp->msg);
}
```

but it didn't work. I think there is a problem with argument of list_for_each_entry, but I don't know why.

plz help me..

Comment: message_list *tmp = 0;

Comment: You should put `struct list_head head1;` into `struct channel` which will behave as a head of list. There is a common misunderstanding: `struct list_head` is both head of list and linking node. Than use `&chs[ch].head1` in your insertion and traversal operations.